# Which libraries I need for projects in Mono Develop to work Properly?

Tags: monodevelop

I want to test each and every project type available on mono. But due to some package dependencies Im unable to run any of "Hello World" project. I have less idea what libraries I need for what.

Few days back I have installed gtk-sharp2 but still while running an VB.net Gtk# or C# Gtk# Im getting compilation errors that cli.Gtk does not exist.

Is there a way through which I can solve all dependencies by one click ?! I atleast once want to try learning linux app programming. Without the proper tools it is not possible. Please help :)

Mono Develop Version : 2.8.6.3
Ubuntu 12.04 32 Bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(better late than never...)*

To install all the necessary library for a monodevelop program on a target machine (not the development machine), all you need is to install mono-complete on the target machine:

`sudo apt-get install mono-complete`

If you want to make sure that double click on the '.exe' file will be launched using muno-runtime (i.e. like any other native program) you may need to install ubuntu-tweak and make than change under **Admin->File types -> DOS/Exe**

Answer (score 0):

Installing Mono Develop form the software center will give you everything you need to run a hello world project. GTK# is required to run monodevelop so you already have it. Try deleting and adding back your references to gtk-sharp and others as sometimes they can be locked to a specific version or strong named key.